# cmake generate Xcode project from existing sources

Tags: macos, cocoa, cmake

This is what I have, when I started generation:

```
iMac:IXCSoftswitch alex$ /usr/bin/cmake -G Xcode .
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /Users/alex/Desktop/ixc-v/IXCSoftswitch,   CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /Users/alex/Desktop/ixc-v/IXCSoftswitch
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:25 (MESSAGE):
  Binary and source directory cannot be the same


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How can I fix it? I'm new to CMake, samples appreciated.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

CMake is used to produce [out-of-source](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#what-is-an-out-of-source-build) builds.

The idea here is that you don't mix the files created during compilation with the original source files. In practice, you usually run CMake from a new, empty build directory and give the path to the source directory as an argument.

```
cd IXCSoftswitch
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G Xcode ..
```

All of the files generated by CMake (which could be a *lot*) will now go into the `build` subdirectory, while your source directory stays clean of build artifacts.

The concept of out-of-source builds may seem strange at first, but it is actually a very convenient way of working once you get used to it.

Comment: looks like this is solution, but i can't find final Xcode project which include all source files. can u please edit answer, where is located?

Comment: This is determined by the project itself. I would suggest you check the documentation that ships with the source code.

Comment: Once you've run `cmake -G Xcode ..`, an Xcode project appears in the build folder. From there, how can one export this project as a module/framework/package that can then be imported into other Xcode workspaces?

Answer (score 11):

From the root of your project directory.

```
cmake -G Xcode -H. -B_build
```

This is similar to the answer above. However, you are manually managing the out of source build. -B sets your target build directory (I happen to prefer _build). I tried looking up -H to double check, but couldn't find it. If memory serves, it specifies where your CMakeLists.txt lives.

I keep this command in a .sh/.bat file (depending). This way, I can keep my scripts that build my project in the root where a new person can easily find them.

Comment: `cmake -H` is one of the CMake **help** aliases. It doesn't take an argument, so the `.` is probably being passed as the source directory. You can specify the source location for your build _explicitly_, if you prefer, with the `-S` flag. The `-S` flag is always optional, and If the source path is your current directory it's not strictly necessary to specify the source location _**at all**_. But I'm just in the habit of always using `cmake -B _build -S .` from the project directory, even though `cmake -B _build` alone would be equivalent. (Other args added as needed.)