# how to generate makefile for a C source file

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling

I've never tried to do this before so this is actually my first time to cross compile a C program.

I have a main.c code file and need to create a makefile for it so i can cross compile this file. This c file has a dependancy curl library. When I compile it in xcode by adding a library, it builds fine. However,i still need to create a makefile for the cross compiling. Can I generate that makefile with xcode? If so, can you please provide some step to step guidance or do i need to use another tool to generate it?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617017/how-can-i-build-a-makefile-project-with-xcode-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alternative approach**

You can use CMake for this task. First of all take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html), that explains CMake basics. Then take a look at [toolchain documentation](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling).

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16700415/cmake-generate-xcode-project-from-existing-sources) too.

Btw OpenWrt has also support for CMake based projects, just look at *uci* and *libubox* packages.